# Тип подчинительной связи

Tags: языкознание

Интересно мнение коллег о типе подчинительной связи в таких словосочетаниях, как "кто-то в шапке", "письмо с очками" ("письмо с очками было спрятано под замок"). Не могу также найти ответа на вопрос о том, можно ли рассматривать как словосочетания такие сочетания слов, как "необходимо ехать", "надо стрелять". Мне кажется, что первые два словосочетания связаны по типу примыкания. Вторая пара слов, на мой взгляд,не могут считаться словосочетаниями, так как являются едиными синтаксическими единицами (сказуемыми безличных предложений).

Comment: > письмо с очками

что, простите? Письмо И очки? Или письмо, в котором написаны очки (например, счет из какой-то игры).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В академической Грамматике-80 различают примыкание беспредложное и предложное, связь в в словосочетаниях "Кто-то в шапке" относят  к предложному примыканию.  В более традиционной классификации это, конечное, управление, так как зависимое слово выражено существительным с предлогом.  А в словосочетаниях типа "надо ехать" - связь примыкание, так как зависимое слово - инфинитив.

Примеры к примыканию из "Синтаксиса ..."Валгиной: "инфинитив легко сочетается с модальными глаголами, глаголами волеизъявления и глаголами движения (могу писать, хочу заниматься; советовать полечиться; поехал отдохнуть), с существительными, мотивированными глаголами или соотносимыми с ними (мысль отдохнуть, желание учиться), а также мотивированными прилагательными, способными присоединять инфинитив (готовый переехать, готов переехать, готовность переехать; обязанный сдать, обязан сдать, обязанность сдать; способный петь, способен петь, способность петь)".

И там же "возможность отдохнуть, причина приехать".

Comment: > А в словосочетаниях типа "надо ехать" - связь примыкание, так как зависимое слово - инфинитив.

А в "буду ехать"?

Comment: >>> "надо ехать" - связь примыкание, так как зависимое слово - инфинитив.  

Насколько помню, как примыкание подобная связь трактуетеся только в случае глагол+инфинитив. Причем первыё гдагол не является служебным или модальным. 
*Я, правда, в силу интересов прошлой жизни более ориентируюсь в общей грамматике, не конкретно русского языка, поэтому могу и ошибаться.*

Comment: Связь существует между словами в словосочетании. Буду ехать -НЕ словосочетание, а сложная форма будущего времени.

Comment: Вот и "надо ехать" очень напоминает некую аналитическую форму. Во всяком случае с позиций общей грамматики я трактовал бы именно так.

Comment: Добавила примеры в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

> > > "кто-то в шапке", "письмо с очками"

Управление. А есть варианты? Какое ж примыкание с предлогом-то?
Касательно смысла вкладывания очков в письмо у меня тоже есть сомнения, но это грамматике не мешает.

> > > "необходимо ехать", "надо стрелять".

Это модальная связь. Это особый вид связи, она не является ни подчинительной, ни сочинительной. Впочем, не уверен, может в русской грамматической традиции она как-то по-другому называется, но за суть я ручаюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Задавая вопрос о сочетаниях типа "кто-то в шляпе", "письмо с очками", я имел в виду то, что зависимые слова в этих сочетаниях не изменяются при склонении главных слов: письмо с очками, письма с очками, письму с очками, письмом с очками, о письме с очками. То же при склонении "кто-то в шляпе". Как известно, примыкают неизменяемые слова (обычно в таком случае имеют ввиду наречия, деепричасти, инфинитив, сравнит. степень прилагательного). Подобную интерпретацию я встречал в одном солидном тесте, где в словосочетании "его тетрадь" определялась связь примыкание.

Comment: А можно "письмо с очками" заменить на что-то более понятное с точки зрения смысла?

Comment: Это словосочетание я встретил в цитате из И.Гончарова ("Письмо с очками было спрятано под замок"), которая была помещена в упражнение из старого, но уважаемого мною учебника Л.А.Шевченко, Н.М.Пипченко "Пособие по русскому языку для поступающих в вузы", с.135

Comment: О боже! Ну там же без контекста и не понять, о чем речь.     
От Ильи Ивановича прячут письмо и очки.

В любом случае склонять тут, имхо, бесполезно. Падежом подчиненного слова управляет не подчиняющее, а предлог. Но то, что здесь не согласование - это и так ясно.

Comment: Притяжательные местоимения "его", "её", "их" не изменяются, они примыкают. Тесты "ЕГЭ", школьная программа.

Comment: Не по теме.   behemothus! На страничке с другим вопросом, где я писала о проблемах с комментариями, у меня вообще исчезла надпись "добавить комментарий". Это может быть "глюк" браузера? Что делать-то? Заранее большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Ларf, на каждый вопрос/ответ допустимы не более 4 комментариев от одного участника

Comment: Может, у Вас просто больше прав? С такими-то баллами!

Comment: Я понял. Оно не сразу срабатывает. Кнопка пропадает через некоторое время.